# Magento $this->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager') returns false

Tags: magento, pagination, toolbar, pager

I have a problem with pagination in one of magento shops.

Magento 1.7.0.2

I was digging, and digging deeper, and then i found a problem that i can't go through.

In **core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php:808**

```
$this->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager')
```

Return: *bool(false)*

(I checked it by returning it in getPagerHtml and then var_dump it in frontpage).

I can't find what *getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager')* exactly stands for.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Is this an issue with one of the standard Magento actions using the toolbar pager (catalog search, category view, etc.), or an issue with some custom action? When `getChild()` returns `false`, this usually means that there is no proper `<block name="product_list_toolbar_pager" />` defined in the layout files for the current action or update handle.

Comment: Unfortunately i have `<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>` in catalog.xml (which is default) file, so problem must be somewhere else. I'm using blanco layout if does it matter. Pagination disappeared suddenly, but i can't be sure that noone changed anything, thats why i need go to place, where is getChild taken from.

Comment: And i'm not using any other custom action. Its standard Magento catalog.

Comment: No, I didn't. Project returns in next month so i'll write something about it when i'll find solution.

Comment: I have this exact issue... Suddenly, no more toolbar_pager. I will report back when I resolve it, as this question is top of Google and could do with being answered.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the block code from the edit cms page for the home page and add this to your local.xml

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" />
            </block>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

The location for the pager block class is : app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Pager.php

The pager template file is at: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/pager.phtml

Hope it helps.